# How to ignore missing files specified with eslint cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, eslint

I have to autogenerate the command to run eslint over a set of files, and sometimes one or more of the patterns/files I specify in the command might not match any files.
For example:
`eslint -c config1.json src/app/m*/*.js src/app/a*/*.js`.
In this command, if the pattern `src/app/m*/*.js` doesn't match anything, it throws an error: `No files matching the pattern "src/app/m*/*.js" were found` .

I'm looking for a way for eslint to ignore the files that are not found here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line option `--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern`, e.g.:

```bash
eslint --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern -c config1.json src/app/m*/*.js src/app/a*/*.js
```

Quoting the [ESLint CLI Options docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface#options):

```
--no-error-on-unmatched-pattern  Prevent errors when pattern is unmatched
```